# Module was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for can't be guaranteed

Tags: ios, xcode, module, swift5, xcode12

Recently I face this compile time warning for a SDK.
Does it means it is not build with the  Target setting "Build Libraries for Distribution"?.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 23):

You need to set `Build Libraries for Distribution` in the Project `Build Settings` to `No` then it will disappear.

Comment: I think you have to come to an agreement with @Jafar's answer

Comment: @Petar Setting it to `No` fixes the issue not to `Yes`

Comment: @SwiftiSwift answer fixed my issue on Xcode 12.5

Comment: That fixes it, but can anyone share what it exactly this warning means and what the impact is to ignoring it? If you do want to build for distribution and get this warning, what steps should you take to ensure your distribution build works as expected?

Comment: @knarf It means you lose XCFramework compatibility. If you aren't distributing XCFrameworks, don't worry about it. The issue was you had a dependency that did not have it enabled, therefor you could not distribute yours with the guarantee you would not break the ABI.

Comment: @SwiftiSwift I had to set it to YES to get rid of the warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you set `Build Libraries for Distribution` to `Yes`, it will disappear.

Comment: In my case they are set to 'YES' but still the error occurs, ideas?

Comment: The other answer suggest the opposite, set it to YES, either way they don't provide any information what may cause the warning.

Comment: In MyCase set Yes to resovled

Comment: What about setting the above in a swift package?

Comment: This is a good case of doubleThink - I am  starting to believe that these 2 mutually exclusive responses are both true...   A bit Orwellian.....    : )