# Can we remove dependencies from .framework file and add them separately in end user app?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks, libraries

I'm making a custom framework, which included third-party libraries due to these libraries my framework file size is increasing. Is there any way we can remove third-party libraries from the .framework file and if the end-user wants to use the functionality of those libraries, he adds them separately.

If I remove dependencies then the framework file is not generated.

Can anyone please help related this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You *must* remove third-party libraries from your framework and have the end-user add them. It is incorrect to bundle them as you're doing. This leads to duplicated symbols and undefined behavior.

The most common way to do what you're describing is with a package manager, particularly [SPM](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager) and/or [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org).

If you do this by hand, you'll need to link the dependent frameworks, but mark them as "do not embed." Doing this correctly by hand can be a bit cumbersome and fragile, which is why it's almost always done with package managers.

Comment: Currently, we are supporting cocoapods , We are using NFCPassportReader library , this library is not allowing us to create cocoapods (got error on podspec lint , validation failed)
Error : Module 'NFCPassportReader' was not compiled with library evolution support;

Comment: The CocoaPods question is addressed here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9232. The precise way to apply this depends on the relevant podspecs and podfiles. If the CP issue doesn't answer the question, you should edit this question to include all the relevant information about your CP setup and the precise errors you're getting. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162207/module-was-not-compiled-with-library-evolution-support-using-it-means-binary-co